# Find a dot in a text file and add a newline to the file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-requests, wxpython

I read from a file, if it finds a `"."`, it should add a newline `"\n"` to the text and write it back to the file. I tried this code but still have the problem.

```
inp = open('rawCorpus.txt', 'r')
out = open("testFile.text", "w")

for line in iter(inp):
    l = line.split()
    if l.endswith(".")
       out.write("\n")
    s = '\n'.join(l)
print(s)
out.write(str(s))
inp.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am reading a file if it find a "." or end of a sentence, it should add a newline and then continue the splitting.

Comment: you text file is big? or not?

Comment: Give an example of the input and the output file.

Comment: @TheAfghan: your input text file is just one line? like bla.hi.hello.ss.dd or it is multiline?

Comment: @TheAfghan: because my code is so efficient for multiline files ( as your format ).

Comment: Yes, the text file include 12000 words

Comment: @TheAfghan: "yes" means multiline or one line?

Comment: Multiline of text, bro

Comment: @TheAfghan: check my UPDATE box ( in my answer )...

Comment: @TheAfghan: output new lines depends on your text viewer too! because in some text editors "\n" is a new line but in some others "\r\n" is a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own solution, but still I want one more newline after ".", that this solution not did this
    read_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('rawCorpus.txt')]
    words = []

```
my_save_data = open("my_saved_data.txt", "w")

   for lines in read_lines:

   words.append(lines)


for word in words:
   w = word.rstrip().replace('.', '\n.')
   w = w.split()
   my_save_data.write(str("\n".join(w)))
   print("\n".join(w))

my_save_data.close()
```

Comment: "but still I want one more newline after "." "... so...you can use two "\n" characters...like "\n\n" did you try that?

Answer (score 5):

**Try This ( Normal way ):**

```
with open("rawCorpus.txt", 'r') as read_file:
    raw_data = read_file.readlines()


my_save_data = open("testFile.text", "a")

for lines in raw_data:

    if "." in lines:

        re_lines = lines.replace(".", ".\r\n")
        my_save_data.write(re_lines)

    else:
        my_save_data.write(lines + "\n")

my_save_data.close()
```

**if your text file is not big you can try this too :**

```
with open("rawCorpus.txt", 'r') as read_file:
    raw_data = read_file.read()

re_data = raw_data.replace(".", ".\n")

with open("testFile.text", "w") as save_data:
    save_data.write(re_data)
```

**UPDATE** ( output new lines depends on your text viewer too! because in some text editors "\n" is a new line but in some others "\r\n" is a new line. ) :

**input sample :**

> This is a book. i love it.
>
> This is a apple. i love it.
>
> This is a laptop. i love it.
>
> This is a pen. i love it.
>
> This is a mobile. i love it.

**Code:**

```
last_buffer = []
read_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('input.txt')]

my_save_data = open("output.txt", "a")


for lines in read_lines:

    re_make_lines = lines.split(".")

    for items in re_make_lines:

        if items.replace(" ", "") == "":
            pass

        else:

            result = items.strip() + ".\r\n"
            my_save_data.write(result)

my_save_data.close()
```

**Ouput Will Be :**

> This is a book.
>
> i love it.
>
> This is a apple.
>
> i love it.
>
> This is a laptop.
>
> i love it.
>
> This is a pen.
>
> i love it.
>
> This is a mobile.
>
> i love it.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but now it does not split the words line by line. My post is do split words line by line even in ur solution I added the split("\n").

Comment: @TheAfghan: so ...plz write your IO sample in your question, i will check it.

Comment: I want read words line by line from sentences, when a sentence end with ".", just it should add a newline after "."

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the string `s` in every loop with `s = '\n'.join(l)`.

Allocate `s = ''` as empty string before the for-loop and add the new lines during every loop, e.g. with `s += '\n'.join(l)` (short version of `s = s + '\n'.join(l)`

This should work:

```
inp = open('rawCorpus.txt', 'r')
out = open('testFile.text', 'w')

s = ''  # empty string

for line in iter(inp):
    l = line.split('.')
    s += '\n'.join(l)  # add new lines to s

print(s)
out.write(str(s))

inp.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was dont know this, but my question is if during the reading it fine an ".", it should add a newline.

Comment: This replaces `.` with `\n`, as the line is split up at the `.` and the parts are joined again with `\n`.

Comment: Sorry, your solution is overwriting to the file. I tested

Comment: Yes, the `out` file is overwritten.

Comment: It should not replace **.** with **\n**. but when find the . it should add a newline